# Как сделать передачу аргументов?

Tags: javascript

Как правильно сделать, чтобы проходил тест?

Задание: Cоздайте класс EventEmitter для управления событиями. У этого класса должны быть следующие методы:
.on(event, callback) - добавить обработчик события

.off(event, callback) - удалить обработчик события

.once(event, callback) - добавить обработчик события, который сработает единожды

.emit(event, [...arg]) - вызвать все обработчики события event, можно передать аргументы

Расширьте EventEmitter классом BroadcastEventEmitter так, чтобы была возможность вызвать все обработчики всех событий:
emit("*", [...arg]) - вызвать все обработчики событий, можно передать аргументы

```
class EventEmitter {
 constructor() {
       this.events = {};
 }

 on(eventName, callback) {
     !this.events[eventName] && (this.events[eventName] = []);
     this.events[eventName].push(callback);
 }

 off(eventName, callback) {
     this.events[eventName] = this.events[eventName].filter(eventCallback => callback !== eventCallback);}

once(eventName, callback) {
   this.events[eventName] = this.events[eventName] || [];
     const onceEvent = () => {
         callback();
         this.off(eventName, onceEvent);
     }
     this.events[eventName].push(onceEvent);
     return this;
 }

 emit(eventName, args) {
    const event = this.events[eventName];
    event && event.forEach(callback => callback.call(null, args));
 }
}

class BroadcastEventEmitter extends EventEmitter {
 emit(event, ...args) {
     if (event === '*') {
         Object.keys(this.events).forEach((e) => super.emit(e, ...args));
     } else {
         super.emit(event, ...args);
     }
 }}
```

Не проходит тест:
тестирование класса BroadcastEventEmitter

✓ проверка наследования от EventEmitter (1ms)

✓ вызов всех событий

✕ передача аргументов (4ms)

```
  ● тестирование класса BroadcastEventEmitter › передача аргументов

expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Expected: 1, 2
Received: 1

Number of calls: 1

  163 |     emitter.emit('*', ...args);
  164 | 
> 165 |     expect(mockFirstListener).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...args);
      |                               ^
  166 |     expect(mockSecondListener).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...args);
  167 |   });
  168 | });

  at Object.toHaveBeenCalledWith test.js:165:31)
```

Comment: Я кажется понял, где ошибка, но лучше поподробнее распишите задачу. Что из себя должен представлять объект эвента в колбэке хэндлера, например `emitter.on('event', (event) => console.log); emitter.emit('event', 1, 2, 3)`? `console.log` просто должен вывести массив с аргументами `[1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: @ВикторияМаригольц Все дополнения в сам вопрос пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

В методе `BroadcastEventEmitter.emit`, в обращении к методу наследующего класса `super.emit(event, ...args)`, для передачи использовался оператор `rest`. Из-за него передавался только 1 аргумент, самый первый.

```js
class EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    this.events = {};
  }

  on(eventName, callback) {
    !this.events[eventName] && (this.events[eventName] = []);
    this.events[eventName].push(callback);
  }

  off(eventName, callback) {
    this.events[eventName] = this.events[eventName].filter(eventCallback => callback !== eventCallback);
  }

  once(eventName, callback) {
    this.events[eventName] = this.events[eventName] || [];
    const onceEvent = (args) => {
      callback.call(onceEvent, args);
      this.off(eventName, onceEvent);
    };
    this.events[eventName].push(onceEvent);
    return this;
  }

  emit(eventName, ...args) {
    const event = this.events[eventName];
    event && event.forEach(callback => callback.call(null, ...args));
  }
}

class BroadcastEventEmitter extends EventEmitter {
  emit(event, ...args) {
    if (event !== '*') return void(super.emit(event, args));
    Object.keys(this.events).forEach((e) => super.emit(e, args));
  }
}

const emitter = new BroadcastEventEmitter();

emitter.on('event', (args) => console.log(args));
emitter.once('event3', (args) => console.log(args));

emitter.emit('event3', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
emitter.emit('event', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Попробуйте, прогоните через тест, если что, поправлю ответ.

Comment: Тест не проходит, еще и тест "добавление `единоразового` слушателя (3ms)" перестал проходить, к сожалению(( То есть, в методе EventEmitter.once все как надо

Comment: Если поменять метод BroadcastEventEmitter.emit на ваш вариант, в целом изменений не произойдет, тест не проходит

Comment: @ВикторияМаригольц у вас скорее всего аргументы вот тут потерялись `const onceEvent = () => {callback(); this.off(eventName, onceEvent); }`. Позже исправлю свой ответ.

Comment: @ВикторияМаригольц исправил, попробуйте.

Comment: Теперь так:   Тестирование класса EventEmitter
    ✓ добавление слушателя события (4ms)
    ✓ удаление слушателя события (1ms)
    ✓ добавление `единоразового` слушателя (1ms)
   ***✕ передача аргументов (8ms)**
  тестирование класса BroadcastEventEmitter
    ✓ проверка наследования от EventEmitter (1ms)
    ✓ вызов всех событий (1ms)
   ✕ передача аргументов (3ms)

Comment: @ВикторияМаригольц я сам могу где-то этот тест запуcтить?

Comment: Нет, у нас на платформе он

Comment: вот весь тест: 
● тестирование класса EventEmitter › передача аргументов

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected
    + Received

      Array [
        Object {
          "type": "return",
          "value": Array [
    +       Array [
              "value",
    +       ],
          ],
        },Object {
          "type": "return",
          "value": Array [
    +       Array [
              "value",
    +       ],
          ],
        },
      ]

Comment: 108 |     emitter.emit('secondEvent', argument);
      109 | 
    > 110 |     expect(mockFirstListener.mock.results).toEqual([
          |                                            ^
      111 |       { type: 'return', value: [argument] },
      112 |       { type: 'return', value: [argument] },
      113 |     ]);

      at Object.toEqual test.js:110:44)

Comment: ● тестирование класса BroadcastEventEmitter › передача аргументов

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: 1, 2
    Received: [1, 2]

    Number of calls: 1

      162 |     emitter.emit('*', ...args);
      163 | 
    > 164 |     expect(mockFirstListener).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...args);
          |                               ^
      165 |     expect(mockSecondListener).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...args);
      166 |   });
      167 | });

      at Object.toHaveBeenCalledWith test.js:164:31)

Comment: @ВикторияМаригольц Изменил, попробуйте так. Если уж сейчас не пройдет, то уже не знаю. Тест сообщает что вместо 2 аргументов приходит только 1 - первый, остальные теряются. Ошибка связана с операторами `rest` в методах `emit` обоих классов, где-то они могут быть лишние или наоброт их не хватает.

Comment: Не проходит, спасибо за попытки, что-то странное

Comment: Вопрос решился просто, все как у вас, но в строчке `Object.keys(this.events).forEach((e) => super.emit(e, ...args));` добавить оператор _rest_